# Prevent upload of ssh keys using vsftp

Tags: security, ssh, ftp

I'm configuring vsftpd for uploads from a device on my network.  FTP is needed for legacy reasons.  This is something I cannot change, no matter how badly I would like to.  So, please don't suggest that I not use ftp! That interface is burned into the firmware of a device I must interface with and cannot change or control.

My issue: I want to prevent shell access (or any other type of access beyond transferring files) to the greatest extent possible.

I am configuring a shell of `/usr/sbin/nologin`.  In the interest of defense-in-depth (to mitigate against accidental changes to the shell, for instance) I am interested in any other ideas you might have.

For instance, I am considering creating a `.ssh` directory into the account's home directory, owned `root:root` mode 0550, with the immutable bit set.  This would be to prevent the device's account from being able to configure SSH access for itself.

Is there a better way to prevent SSH keys from being uploaded via vsftpd?  Are there any other files or directories you would "ban" from being uploaded in the interest of security?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a step back and disable SSH for that/those account/s entirely.

In your `sshd_config`, you can list which users may login via SSH, or you can list which users are disallowed. The relevant keywords are

```
AllowGroups
         This keyword can be followed by a list of group name patterns, separated by
         spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for users whose primary group or
         supplementary group list matches one of the patterns.
AllowUsers
         This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by
         spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of
         the patterns.
```

and their counterparts `DenyUsers` and `DenyGroups`.

You could also confuse the issue further by changing the name of the ssh authorized keys file, so that even if someone were to upload a file to `.ssh/authorized_keys`, SSH would not be using that file. The relevant keyword is

```
AuthorizedKeysFile
         Specifies the file that contains the public keys that can be used for user
         authentication.
```

Or you could choose to reject ssh key authentication altogether, although I would generally not recommend that.

#### Addition:

You can also use vsftpd's `deny_file` option to limit file uploads within the ftpd as well, and I should advise you to have a look into your `pam` configuration to block users from logging in via other methods than SSH.

Comment: JennyD's method seems much superior to me than any "hack" based around trying to fix a `.ssh` directory; it uses the mechanism the daemon provides for exactly this kind of control.  It's also what I use myself.